# Why is the sound "cha" spelled as ちゃ rather than ちぁ?

Tags: spelling

I was wondering why is the sound "cha" spelled with a ゃ rather than a ぁ.
きゃ, for example, is "kya"; so shouldn't ちゃ be more like... "chya"? The same goes for しゃ.
I suppose "sha" and "cha" kind of already sound like "shya" and "chya", respectively; is this why or is there another reason?
Additionally, is there even such a thing as a small ぁ, if ゃ has this role anyway?

Comment: Apologies for the silly question. I just found myself wondering about this and couldn't find a definite answer anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: I actually don't think it's a silly question at all :-)

Comment: That's a relief :) I was really curious about this but I feared that I was just nitpicking by looking for the "why" rather than settling for the "how"... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from being a silly question. For one thing, the half-sized vowels (ぁ、ぃ、ぅ、ぇ、ぉ） didn't actually exist in the first place. They are mainly used while writing down a spoken sentence where the speaker insisted on the vowels, even more than the actual word would require. For example, you could find the sentence 「とぉぉても嬉{うれ}しいです！」 in a manga, that would mean that the character strongly insisted on the お sound in 「とても」. In English you would simply report that as "I'm veeeeery happy!".

Now, going back to the main subject. The Japanese is initially an only-spoken language, their writing system is entirely taken from the Chinese, even the kanas, which are all *largely* simplified kanjis. In our case that matters because **even before** their writing system was invented, the sounds "cha", "chu" and "cho" existed, but not "che", "chya", "chyu" and "chyo", so the "cha"&co. took their place in the writing system. Why bother to create a new notation for something which works the same way as the other consonnants when there's a system which works just fine? Of course, the same goes with the sh- (and its j- derivative).

Hope my explanations were clear enough, I tried my best for explaining a Japanese fact in English, while being French.

Comment: Ca va, tu t'en sors bien ;)

Comment: Bravo! Vraiment une excellente explication.

Comment: Hahaha, thank you :) Your explanations were incredibly clear and touched exactly the points I was curious about.